# Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database:

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

hello i have a sqlite database, i hhave a table called Archive inside, but using my code it is saying Finisar.SQLite.SQLite Ex ception: SQL logic er ror or missing database:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=./database.db;Version=2;New=False;Compress=True;");

                this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
                    DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Archive", cn);
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    da.Fill(DT);
                    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                cn.Close();
```